# Amazon S3 PUT Error...BadDigest?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

So I have this script that has been putting files up on S3 no problem.  But what I noticed is when I use a file that has a space, it fails and gives me a "BadDigest" error if I just leave the name alone, and if I do a str_replace on it and remove all of the "-", "_", and " " I get a "RequestTimeout" error.

However if I change the name on my computer and upload it works fine...so I assume that the characters are the cause.

How do I cleanse this to make it work?  I saw something that there may be a UTF8 issue but wasn't sure how to correct it.

```
$s3 = new AmazonS3();

$response = $s3->create_object(
    'bucketName',
    'userFiles/marie 123.jpg',
    array(
       'fileUpload'  => '/var/www/uploads/marie 123.jpg',
       'acl'         => AmazonS3::ACL_OPEN,
       'contentType' => 'image/jpeg',
       'storage'     => AmazonS3::STORAGE_STANDARD,
    )
);

print_r($response); die();
```

Comment: Can you share the code you are using to upload the files? Right now there is not enough info in your question to help.